# example of getting data from server Nodejs with angular smart table

Tags: angularjs, node.js, smart-table

I'm using Angular smart table to display data from my database using Node.js.
My problem is that I don't know how to get data from the server with `$http.get` or `$http.post`, passing filters and the number of the current page.

This is the [documentation](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-pipe) about a fake call to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You use the GET verb to fetch data (though you can also use POST to carry your parameters on the request body). using a Angular service you could request your data like so

with GET
in your service

```
return $http.get('url/to/data', {
    params: {id: id}}
)
```

or by using path params

```
return $http.get('url/to/data/' + id)
```

in your controller

```
myHttpService().get(id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.tableData = response.data;
})
```

go through the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs, they are very helpful show several examples for remote server calls

then in your smart table markup

```
<tbody">
<tr ng-repeat="row in tableData">
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

to get current page, use the [st-paginate](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-pagination) directive to add a pagination to your

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="5"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

use the [st-search](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-filter) directive to filter your data globally or by rows

```
<th st-sort="id">id</th>
<th st-sort="name">name</th>
```

Comment: In the documentation example, it's selecting 1000 rows and then filter it and get 10 items according to the current page. What i'm searching for, is how can i get just 10 rows according to the filter and the number of the current page ??